# positioning div inside a table

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have a calendar implemented with a table since a calendar is a tabular data. I am wondering about how to implement events so that the position of the div event is updated as one scrolls resizes the window (which also resizes the table).

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bCZl31OZuCVN0q8vnGp0?p=preview

If you resize the frame which divides the editor and the preview you see that the event is moved to a different date (from the correct 17th of October).

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      table,td,tr{border:1px solid gray;border-collapse:collapse;}
      td{height:40px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="events">
    <div class="event" style="background:red;position:relative; top:110px; left:200px; width:100px;">Meet John Doe</div>
  </div>
<table width="100%">
        <tbody>

        <tr>
           <td>

            </td><td>
                1
            </td><td>
                2
            </td><td>
                3
            </td><td>
                4
            </td><td>
                5
            </td><td>
                6
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                7
            </td><td>
                8
            </td><td>
                9
            </td><td>
                10
            </td><td>
                11
            </td><td>
                12
            </td><td>
                13
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                14
            </td><td>
                15
            </td><td>
                16
            </td><td>
                17
            </td><td>
                18
            </td><td>
                19
            </td><td>
                20
            </td>
        </tr><tr>

            <td>
                21
            </td><td>
                22
            </td><td>
                23
            </td><td>
                24
            </td><td>
                25
            </td><td>
                26
            </td><td>
                27
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                28
            </td><td>
                29
            </td><td>
                30
            </td><td>
                31
            </td><td>

            </td><td>

            </td><td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick the div inside the correct `<td>`? See [this solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/NU0ASJHlT9WYteUg1tCj?p=preview)

```
<td>
    17
    <div class="event" style="background:red;">Meet John Doe</div>                
</td>
```

Otherwise your would have to dynamically calculate the position with javascript, but that could get messy. A pure HTML/CSS solution should definitely be preferred.

Comment: yes, but if you change the width of the div for events that span multiple days, it will not work...

Comment: Well in that case you could assign a `max-width` and `overflow: visible` to the `<td>`. You would just have to handle wrapping around weekends when you create the divs. But you would have to do that either way. See [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPhaeEhvU8hO9S2cORfy?p=preview).

Comment: thanks, your suggestion is on the right track. The remaining problem is that when you resize the frame the div inside should also resize. I mean if the event spans two days for example, it should remain the same when you make the frame smaller. Right now it spans over multiple days when you make the frame smaller.

Comment: I don't see a good way of doing that in pure CSS. It looks like you'll have to use JS/jQuery after all. On resize you could simply set the `width` of the event to the sum of all the [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)s of the `<td>`s it spans.